# What is the word for the intense desire to physically hurt a person?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm looking for a word that essentially means the intense desire to hurt/maim/injure someone - using it for one of the characters in a short story I'm writing. Thanks!

Comment: Context matters. Sadism? Bloodlust? Hatred?

Comment: And is it directed towards a specific person, or is it a more general desire to hurt anyone?

Answer (score 1):

**Bloodlust** - The intense desire to kill or maim.

[Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloodlust)

Answer (score 1):

[Bloodthirsty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloodthirstiness) means:

> eager to hurt or kill, enjoying the sight of violence or bloodshed

[Blood-hungry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloodhungry) means almost same:

> eager to kill or shed blood.

There is no *hyphen* in bloodthirsty.

[Merriam-Webster and Wiktionary]